# Group or cross function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with some data

```
ID  Topic
1   A
1   B
2   B
3   C
4   A
4   B
5   A
```

Total 5 records

I like to count when same ID with Topic A then count B as well. So the result count total 5  ID2 = 2 (A and B) and ID4 = 2 (A and B) and ID5 = 1 (A) 
Not sure how to count like this. Thank you

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: But you don't have _total 5 records_. Did you mean that you have 5 distinct values in ID column? I don't understand "ID2" since there is only a single row where ID = 2 but I think I understand "ID4" since there are 2 rows (A and B) with ID = 4. Can you clarify (and correct your formatting)?

Comment: I really do not know the logic for this , the output count total count 5 records

Comment: If you don't - then no one else does and guessing is all anyone can do. Many will not attempt that.

Comment: Apologies for that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SMor mentioned, this question is not clear.

If you only know the table above and the result is 5, and don't know the logic for calculating the result, we can think of it as getting the result to get the number of unique IDs in this table.

Because there is only one logic to get the value of 5 in the table above.

If so, you can try the following.

```
  SELECT count(id) result
  FROM (
      select id
      from your_table
      group by id
  ) A
```

Or If you want to just get 5 records (any topic about the same ID) then try this.

```
SELECT id, max(topic)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
```